# Tsfresh takess too long that the computer can handle

Tags: python, feature-extraction

I am trying to use tsfresh feature extraction library in python 3.7.1 using efficient parameters with a test file (24 rows x 366 columns)

it never stops and keeps processing and i tried to run same library on a different laptop with installed python 2.17.16 but the tsfresh library did not work.

what should i do?

[image]

[image]

```
# Import Data from CSV file
#import csv
#with open('T7.csv') as T7:
#    reader = csv.reader(T7)
#    try: 
#        for row in reader:
#            print(row)
#    finally: 
#        T7.close()
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

style.use('ggplot')


#from tsfresh import extract_features #as tsfreshobj
#from tsfresh import MinimalFeatureExtractionSettings
from tsfresh.feature_extraction import extract_features, EfficientFCParameters 
#X = extract_features(df, column_id='id', column_sort='time')
y=pd.read_csv ('1.csv')#, skiprows=1)

#y=np.loadtxt('T7_2.csv')#, 
             #unpack=True,
            # delimiter=',')
#y1=tsfreshobj.feature_extraction.extraction.generate_data_chunk_format(y)
#y2=tsfreshobj.feature_extraction.feature_calculators.absolute_sum_of_changes(y1)
#y1=extract_features(y, feature_extraction_settings=MinimalFeatureExtractionSettings)
print (y)

# from tsfresh.feature_extraction import MinimalFeatureExtractionSettings
y1=extract_features(y, column_id='time', default_fc_parameters=EfficientFCParameters())#, column_sort='time')
print (y)
print (y1)
plt.plot(y1)

print (y)
plt.title ('some numbers')
plt.ylabel('Y axis')
plt.xlabel ('X axis')


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the `MinimalFCParameters` if it works at all? With these, it should be finished in a matter of seconds.

One problem could be, that you need to wrap your code in a `if __name__ == "__main__"`, otherwise the multiprocessing library will have a problem.

If this does not help, you could use any of the techniques I described e.g. [here](https://nils-braun.github.io/tsfresh-on-cluster-1/) to parallelize the `tsfresh` computation.

The issue with installing `tsfresh` on your other machine is unrelated to `tsfresh` - the error message shows that you did not have internet connection while calling `pip install`.